# Can we put the lite version of any app on the app store after launching of sdk 3.0?

Tags: iphone

HI all ,

After launching the sdk 3.0 .Did apple refused to launch of the lite and the standard version of one app on the app store , i heard that  apple will kill the app if any app have two version like one lite and another standard cause it is increasing the redundancy on the app store.if any one know or have reference link pls provide

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see plenty of "iPhone OS 3.0 tested" lite apps. Someone's feeding you a line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/02/08/app-store-demo-no-lite-yes/

Lite ones are fine, you can leave out features, but you can't time-cap it - ie have it stop working after 15 days.  Note that while you can leave out features, you can't leave out features key to the app itself.

So a compass app - lite or not, should tell you which way north is, but a lite version might leave out skinnable options, for example.